# my Ajax response is not an object. how do I fix so I can display key results fields

Tags: json, ajax

I am trying to pull from this itunes API to display two results.  The api is returning a large response but not as an object.  I tried using JSON.parse(response.results[i].length) to iterate through the results... but not working.

```
queryTVURL = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=big%20bang%20theory&kind=feature-movie&country=US&media=all&limit=0&lang=en_us&version=2&explicit=Yes"


$.ajax({
    url: queryTVURL,
    method: "GET"
}).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response));

        if (response.results.length > 0) {

            for (i = 0; i < JSON.parse(response.results[i].length); i++) {
                if (response.results[i].kind === "tv-episode") {
                    console.log(response.results[i].kind);
                    console.log(response.results[i].previewUrl)
                }
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add what the console.log output so that others can help you

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.js:3818 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/reina/OneDrive/Desktop/UCF%20Coding%20Bootcamp/Homework/HWK8/Flick-Pick/test%20files/itunes.js:30:26)
    at mightThrow (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:29)
    at process (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12) undefined

Comment: Object
resultCount
:
16
results
:
(16) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: the object above is displayed as an object using   console.log(JSON.parse(response));  otherwise it's just one big {}